# Ho do I prevent GitVersion from including the commit hash in the version number?

Tags: git, azure-devops, semantic-versioning, gitversion

I've just started using GitVersion in TFS 2018.3 (VSTS, Azure DevOps), and really trying the easy option. I use the [GitVersion TFS marketplace](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) task straight out of the box. I tagged the master branch with 1.1.0.0 and ran the build.

The build log shows:

> 2018-10-25T15:39:53.1843138Z INFO [10/25/18 17:39:53:08] Updating
>   assembly info files 2018-10-25T15:39:53.1843138Z INFO [10/25/18
>   17:39:53:18] Found 42 files 2018-10-25T15:39:53.3123172Z
>   [section]Async Command Start: Update Build Number 2018-10-25T15:39:53.3123172Z Update build number to
>   1.2.0-alpha.354-20181025.1 for build 1107

From that, I would expect a version `1.2.0-alpha.354-20181025.1` but the resulting version in AssemblyInformationalVersion is:

`<Assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.2.0-alpha.354+Branch.develop.Sha.1b44044f1e3324182b9e1f37958b6a4942731e59")>`

or

`<Assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("1.2.0-some_branch_name.1+366.Branch.feature/some_branch_name.Sha.1b44044f1e3324182b9e1f37958b6a4942731e59")>`

Is there a way to prevent displaying the `Branch.develop.Sha.1b...`?

Is this the right way to use that task?

Comment: I think you could do it in specifying the format in the 'GitVersion. yaml' file that you will create at the root of the repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To customize the default settings of GitVersion you should add a GitVersion.yml file in the root of your repository. For example with these contents:

```
mode: ContinuousDeployment
assembly-informational-format: '{SemVer}-{CommitDate}'
branches: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
```

This will result in a version string of `1.2.0-alpha.354-2018-10-25`.

To try if your GitVersion.yml file works correctly, you could open up a command line and execute `GitVersion.exe /updateassemblyinfo`. This works only if you've installed GitVersion locally, e.g. with `choco install GitVersion.Portable`. See also [GitVersion docs](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/command-line/). However executing the `GitVersion.exe /updateassemblyinfo` command will provide you with a full list of variables available for you to include in your GitVersion.yml file.

Comment: Thanks a million. I really required the date in the version... my specific users/testers are very particular about that :)